# Apache Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: when I installed php5-gd

Tags: php, apache, php-gd

I was trying to install php5-gd but after ran this command:

```
yum install php-gd php-tidy
```

and tried to restart apache:

```
httpd -k restart
```

I got the following error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: symbol SSLeay_version, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference
```

Any of you knows why or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be because openSSL hasn't been updated. Could you try updating openSSL via yum and let us know if it works?

```
yum update openssl
```

Comment: didn't work for me (although, problem is with libphp7, not 5). Did yum update and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The php you are trying to load is compiled with more recent version of openssl than you have installed. Most probably you have messed installation using repositories with different versions of openssl libs. Or else for different versions of OS.

`yum list php-gd` and `yum list openssl` `rpm -qf /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` should give you a hint or two.

Answer (score 0):

yum remove httpd

yum clean all

Step1: install fedora 19

Step2: install repository

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/remi-release-19.rpm
```

Step3: Install Apache (httpd) Web server and PHP 5.5.9

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install httpd php php-common
```

Step4:  Install PHP 5.5.9 modules

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

Step5: enable service and run it
    systemctl enable httpd.service

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start ## use restart after update
```

OR
    service httpd start ## use restart after update

Step 6: Create test PHP page to check that Apache, PHP and PHP modules are working

```
add test page to /var/www/html/test.php file and run using localhost/test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment this `libphp5.so` file under `error.conf` file and try to restart the httpd server like:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

If again you are facing issue then check the certificate under the specific location where the `.crt` and `.jks` file exist.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 25:

```
sudo dnf -y remove httpd
sudo dnf -y install httpd
```

I would recommend having a backup of all files and configuration though, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 7

```
yum install -y php php-common
yum install openssl
or 
yum reinstall openssl
systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run

> sudo dnf install libnsl

Comment: Can you include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable.